# Locus of foot of perpendicular

Tags: analytic-geometry

> A circle of radius $r$ passes through the origin $O$ and cuts the axes at $A(a,0)$ and $B(0,b)$. What is the locus of the foot of perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$?

I found the equation of circle passing through $A$, $B$ and $O$ and then found $k/a=h/b$ (taking the foot as $(h,k)$). I also found that $a^2+b^2=4r^2$. What's next?

Comment: Why do you refer to a locus? What is variable here? The centre of the circle through OAB is the midpoint of AB, btw.

Comment: a,b are the variables here.r is the only constant @DavidQuinn

Comment: I don't understand why you introduced a circle. The foot of the perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$ only depends on the point $O$ and the line $A $?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net that's what the question in front of me says.Thats all !

Comment: Strange question then!

Comment: Source http://www.flipkart.com/mathematics-jee-advanced-english-1st/p/itmdmtb7yrngbfrg @mathcounterexamples.net

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\theta$ the polar angle of the perpendicular. Then $a = 2r\sin \theta$, $b= 2r\cos\theta$, and the length of the perpendicular is $r |\sin 2\theta|$. So the locus equation in polar coordinates is $\rho = r|\sin 2\theta|$, which gives a nice [flower](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r+%3D+|sin%282theta%29|+polar+theta+%3D+0...2pi).